# Iterate key value pairs inside list and convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I have a number of lists given in format [image: sample_image]

```
[{"@context":"ABC","entity":"PQR","URL":"abc@yahoo.com"}]
[{"@context":"RST","entity":"UVW","URL":"efg@gmail.com"}]
.............
............
............
```

I want to convert this into pandas dataframe:

```
@context    entity     URL
ABC         PQR        abc@yahoo.com
RST         UVW        efg@gmail.com
...         ...        .......
...         ...        .......
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(L)` ?

Comment: Main question is - what are input data? nested list? csv?

Comment: lists are generated by some system?

Comment: Check edited answer.

Comment: Your image (which we prefer to avoid, because they can't be copy-pasted) makes it seem like your type is weird: you have a list of STRINGS, which represent a one-element list, whose element is a dictionary.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

If there are nested lists first flatten it:

```
from  itertools import chain

L = [[{"@context":"ABC","entity":"PQR","URL":"abc@yahoo.com"}],
     [{"@context":"RST","entity":"UVW","URL":"efg@gmail.com"}]]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(L)))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in L for y in x])

print (df)
  @context            URL entity
0      ABC  abc@yahoo.com    PQR
1      RST  efg@gmail.com    UVW
```

EDIT:

If data are generated another script, the best is create list of all dictionaries and pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
L = [[{"@context":"ABC","entity":"PQR","URL":"abc@yahoo.com"}],
[{"@context":"RST","entity":"UVW","URL":"efg@gmail.com"}]]

L1 = []
for i in L:
    print (i[0])
    #simulate generate dictionaries
    L1.append(i[0])

print (L1)    
[{'@context': 'ABC', 'entity': 'PQR', 'URL': 'abc@yahoo.com'}, 
 {'@context': 'RST', 'entity': 'UVW', 'URL': 'efg@gmail.com'}]


df = pd.DataFrame(L1)
print (df)
  @context            URL entity
0      ABC  abc@yahoo.com    PQR
1      RST  efg@gmail.com    UVW
```

EDIT:

Problem is your data are strings, so first need convert them to list of dicts:

```
import ast

L = ['[{"@context":"ABC","entity":"PQR","URL":"abc@yahoo.com"}]',
     '[{"@context":"RST","entity":"UVW","URL":"efg@gmail.com"}]']

df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in L for y in ast.literal_eval(x)])
print (df)
  @context            URL entity
0      ABC  abc@yahoo.com    PQR
1      RST  efg@gmail.com    UVW
```

Comment: Code is not working for me. Please check the attached txt file of json structure (for now I have pasted only two) of scrapped output. I need to extract keys '@context', '@type','url' as columns as their values as corresonding data.

Comment: Sorry, where is file?

Comment: @James - I think my probklem is I cannot see your acual code for scaping data, is possible share it?

Comment: sorry to irritate you. please check the image attached of the output I have got

Comment: Thankyou so much sir!! everything works fine but just because my url string is quite large it gets copied to new array but shows error as "EOL while scanning string literal". How to overcome this?

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in L for y in x], , columns=['@context', 'entity', 'URL'])```
this code worked really well for me